# Angular 2 - Howto add a Directive to a run-time created Component?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

There are a lot of Angular 2 tutorials about adding components at run-time and none of them covers how to also dynamically add a directive to them, which is also my question; howto achieve this?

What I've tried, is to manually instantiate them, but then I need some Lifecycle Hook helper to trigger ngOnInit, ngOnChanges, ... In other words, the directive's lifecycle is equal to the components lifecycle so I guess, that there should be any helpers.

Thank you.